# Let $A$ be a closed set where every compact subset of $A$ is countable. Then prove that $A$ is also countable.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Let $A$ be a closed set where every compact subset of $A$ is countable. Then prove that $A$ is also countable.

I've bee at this problem since this morning but I have literally no progress. First I thought of proving it with contradiction but then as there was no info of $A$ was given (other than $A$ is closed) I couldn't make any compact subset which is not countable.

Can anyone please help me through this. I don't want full answer rather I want to be nudged to the right direction and want to do it on my own, understand it. Please do help, this is taking forever.

Comment: *Where* is the set $A$ closed?

Comment: No information is given about it. I found the question just as I typed it. I tried to think it is closed on $\mathbb{R}$ though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $A$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$. Suppose that $A$ is uncountable. Then, since $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z}A\cap[n,n+1]$, there is some $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $A\cap[n,n+1]$ is uncountable. But $A\cap[n,n+1]$ is closed and bounded, and therefore it is compact.

A similar proof can be made if we are working on $\Bbb R^n$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. But just asking as I'm curious, can it be answered thinking that it's a closed subset of a different set than $\mathbb{R}$. Can it be answered arbitrarily?

Comment: I see you said about $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can we go further in an abstract space where we can think of solving this?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, it is true on $\Bbb R^n$. On the other hand, it is false on $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $A \subseteq \mathbb R$.

Then for any $n \in \mathbb N$, $A_n = A \cap [-n,n] \subseteq A$ is compact and therefore countable.

As $$A = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$$ is a countable union of countable subsets, $A$ is also countable.

Comment: Thank you too..